# Install psutil on MobaXterm

Tags: pip, dependencies, psutil, mobaxterm

I'm working on MobaXterm and need a python library (`prefect`) requiring `psutil`. When I run `pip3 install psutil` I get the following error : `platform cygwin is not supported`
Then pip loops on older verisons of psutil repeating the same errors again.

How can install psutil on MobaXterm ?
I can't consider installing Linux on my computer for now, although an alternative to MobaXterm could if it's the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try installing Linux subsystem for windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
You can use it as a replacemento to connect to remote machine ( that is what I guess you are using MobaXTerm ) and having a working linux environment.

Comment: It worked thanks, although I'm a bit disappointed to give up MobaXterm as I started to get used to it :(

Comment: @peppie. nice, it would be nice if you mark the answer correct :)